# Angular 2 Return value from function call for each item in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm using Angular 2 with TypeScript, I'm trying to achieve a dynamic class.

Here's my component HTML:

```
<main class="pure-g">
  <div *ngFor="let ex of exs; let i = index; trackBy: index" [className]='columns(i)'>
    {{ex.name}} | {{ex.parts}}
  </div>
</main>
```

Here's my TS:

```
exs: Object[] = [
    {name: 'ex1', parts: ['upper', 'lower']},
    {name: 'ex2', parts: ['upper', 'lower']},
    {name: 'ex3', parts: ['upper', 'lower']},
    {name: 'ex4', parts: ['upper', 'lower']},
    {name: 'ex5', parts: ['upper', 'lower']},
    {name: 'ex6', parts: ['upper', 'lower']},
    {name: 'ex7', parts: ['upper', 'lower']}
];

private _reminder: number = this.exs.length % 6;
private _className: string = "pure-u-";

columns(index) {
    let _class: string;
    if (index <= 5) {
        _class = this._reminder === 0 ? this._className + "1-6" : this._className + "1-" + this._reminder;
    } else {
        _class = this._className + "1-" + this._reminder;
    }

    return _class;
}
```

I'm aiming to execute the columns function for each item passing its index to the function so each item evaluates different class. The result I'm getting is actually:

```
pure-u-1-1
```

For every item, it seems like the execution of the function return className that are bound for all items, instead for each one.

The actual result I thought would be is like so:

```
itemOne iteration -> call columns(index=0) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemTwo iteration -> call columns(index=1) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemThree iteration -> call columns(index=2) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemFour iteration -> call columns(index=3) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemFive iteration -> call columns(index=4) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemSix iteration -> call columns(index=5) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemSeven iteration -> call columns(index=6) -> return 'pure-u-1-1';
```

Comment: what you exactly what ? exact output as last piece of code?

Comment: as i mentioned here's the output i expect: itemOne iteration -> call columns(index=0) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemTwo iteration -> call columns(index=1) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemThree iteration -> call columns(index=2) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemFour iteration -> call columns(index=3) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemFive iteration -> call columns(index=4) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemSix iteration -> call columns(index=5) -> return 'pure-u-1-6';
itemSeven iteration -> call columns(index=6) -> return 'pure-u-1-1';

Comment: in your example `_reminder` will always be 6.

Comment: it's dynamic, the rule is that: the first row will be divided 1/of items or 6 if the row is full. if i have 8 items, 6 will have pure-u-1-6, and the two others will have pure-u-1-2. if i have 9 items 6 will have pure-u-1-6, the three others will have 6 will have pure-u-1-3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it in HTML itself as shown below,

```
 <div *ngFor="let ex of exs; let i = index; trackBy: index"    
       [className]="i < exs.length-1 ? 'pure-u-1-6': 'pure-u-1-1' ">
    {{ex.name}} | {{ex.parts}}
  </div>
```

OR

```
columns(index) {


    private _className: string = "pure-u-";

    let _class: string;
    if (index < this.exs.length-1) {
          _class = this._className + "1-6"  
    } else {
          _class = this._className + "1-" + this.exs.length-index;
    }

    return _class;
}
```

Comment: yeah that's one way to do it, but i prefer to separate logic from DOM. and doing : "i < exs.length-1 ? 'pure-u-1-6': 'pure-u-1-1' " won't work for the next case where i have 8 items, 6 are need to be 1/6 width, while the 2 others should be 1/2 width.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by using `ngClass` directive with ngFor variable like **first** ,**last**,**even** and **odd** . base of your code only the last element got different class

```
<main class="pure-g">
  <div *ngFor="let ex of exs; let i = index;let last=last;trackBy: index" 
          [ngClass]='{'pure-u-1-6' : !last, 'pure-u-1-1':last}'> 
    {{ex.name}} | {{ex.parts}}
  </div>
</main>
```

> it 'is not effective to call a methold like this
>   `[className]='columns(i)'` because it 'is will call in every
>   change detection cycle